# Is it possible to send audio file and doc/pdf file in quick blox chat

Tags: android, ios, quickblox

Is it possible to send audio files and doc/pdf files while chatting in **quick blox**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible. here is some reference code and Link.

```
var fileLocation = NSString(string:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "mp3")!)
    let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: fileLocation, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &error)

    QBRequest.TUploadFile(fileData, fileName: "test.mp3", contentType: " audio/mpeg3", isPublic: false,
                          successBlock: {(response: QBResponse!, uploadedBlob: QBCBlob!) in
                            // Create and configure message

                            // Send message Code


    }, statusBlock: {(request: QBRequest?, status: QBRequestStatus?) in

    }, errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse!) in

        print(response.error?.reasons)
    })
```

Here is reference link for more Detail [ClickHere](https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Send_attachment)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible just the way you send image in quickblox same way you have to send audio file with audio file extension